How do I read a JSON file and access its properties?
I'm attempting to read a JSON file that was was successfully exported using wp_send_json_success however I'm unable to loop through the array in the file since it seems that I can't access $menu->terms. What am I overlooking?
$json_content = file_get_contents( ABSPATH . '/menu.json', true );
$menus = json_decode( $json_content );

if ( ! empty( $menus ) ) {
        foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
            // Get the internal menu by slug.
            $internal_menu = get_term_by( 'slug', 'primary', 'nav_menu' );

            // Check if a menu with the specified name already exists.
            $menu_exists = wp_get_nav_menu_object( 'Primary' );

            if ( $menu_exists ) {
                // If the menu exists, delete it.
                wp_delete_nav_menu( 'Primary' );
            }

            // Create a new menu with the same name.
            $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'Primary' );

            // Build arguments for new menu items.
            $args  = array();
            $index = 0;
           
            if ( ! empty( $menu->terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $menu->terms as $menu_item ) {

                    // Skip if the post status is 'draft'.
                    if ( 'draft' === $menu_item->post_status ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Process menu item based on its type.
                    $args_menu_item = process_menu_item( $menu_item );

                    // Update nav menu item and get the updated ID.
                    $nav_menu_item_update = wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $args_menu_item );

                    // Update the object ID in the arguments.
                    $args_menu_item['menu-item-object-id'] = $nav_menu_item_update;

                    $args[ $index++ ] = $args_menu_item;
                }
            }

            // Update parent ID for menu items.
            update_parent_id( $menu_id, $args );

        }
    }
}

Here's an excerpt from the JSON file that $menu spits out
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "term_id": 4,
      "name": "Primary",
      "slug": "primary",
      "term_group": 0,
      "term_taxonomy_id": 4,
      "taxonomy": "nav_menu",
      "description": "",
      "parent": 0,
      "count": 31,
      "filter": "raw",
      "terms": [
        {
          "ID": 269,
          "post_author": "1",
          "post_date": "2023-06-27 03:46:59",
          "post_date_gmt": "2023-01-01 03:56:36",
          "post_content": "…………………………………………",
          "post_title": "",
          "post_excerpt": "",
          "post_status": "publish",
          "comment_status": "closed",
          "ping_status": "closed",
          "post_password": "",
          "post_name": "269",
          "to_ping": "",
          "pinged": "",
          "post_modified": "2023-06-27 03:46:59",
          "post_modified_gmt": "2023-06-27 03:46:59",
          "post_content_filtered": "",
          "post_parent": 0,
          "guid": "https://www.example.com/?p=269",
          "menu_order": 1,
          "post_type": "nav_menu_item",
          "post_mime_type": "",
          "comment_count": "0",
          "filter": "raw",
          "db_id": 269,
          "menu_item_parent": "0",
          "object_id": "2",
          "object": "page",
          "type": "post_type",
          "type_label": "Front Page",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/",
          "title": "Home",
          "target": "",
          "attr_title": "",
          "description": "…………………………………………&hellip;",
          "classes": [
            ""
          ],
          "xfn": "",
          "menu_item_parent_object_id": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_type": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_title": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_url": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_id": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_post_name": "blank"
        },
        {
          "ID": 277,
          "post_author": "1",
          "post_date": "2023-06-27 03:46:59",
          "post_date_gmt": "2023-01-01 04:01:38",
          "post_content": "…………………………………………",
          "post_title": "About",
          "post_excerpt": "",
          "post_status": "publish",
          "comment_status": "closed",
          "ping_status": "closed",
          "post_password": "",
          "post_name": "277",
          "to_ping": "",
          "pinged": "",
          "post_modified": "2023-06-27 03:46:59",
          "post_modified_gmt": "2023-06-27 03:46:59",
          "post_content_filtered": "",
          "post_parent": 0,
          "guid": "https://www.example.com/?p=277",
          "menu_order": 2,
          "post_type": "nav_menu_item",
          "post_mime_type": "",
          "comment_count": "0",
          "filter": "raw",
          "db_id": 277,
          "menu_item_parent": "0",
          "object_id": "272",
          "object": "page",
          "type": "post_type",
          "type_label": "Page",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/about/",
          "title": "About",
          "target": "",
          "attr_title": "",
          "description": "…………………………………………&hellip;",
          "classes": [
            ""
          ],
          "xfn": "",
          "menu_item_parent_object_id": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_type": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_title": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_url": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_id": "blank",
          "menu_item_parent_post_name": "blank"
        },


Is the path to the file correct? If you var_dump($menus), what does it show you? If it's null, then the json could not be decoded or the structure is deeper than the nesting limit.

@AnttiKoskinen, yes, it's the file path is correct and var_dump($menus) returns the JSON output.

what do you mean by "unable to read loop" ? edit your question to show what is in $menu just before the loop.

@mmm, I've added an example

If you want to loop the menus from the json, then you need to use the data attribute where the menus actually are.
Also you may want to use the current iteration $menu slug in the get_term_by() call, unless you specifically want to check for existance of "Primary" menu on each iteration. If that is the case, then it might be more efficient to do the checking outside of the loop so it is done only once.
$menus = json_decode( $json_content );

if ( ! empty( $menus->data ) ) {
    foreach ( $menus->data as $menu ) {
        // code...
    }
}


It looks like you're trying to iterate over all the items in the terms array, but terms is under data, not directly in menu, so your code is just missing the intermediate reference to data, i.e.:
if ( ! empty( $menu->data->terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $menu->data->terms as $menu_item ) {
...

